# Cannot import data as NetCDF

Tags: import

This might be obvious but I cannot import a dataset.

```
Import["data.nc", "Datasets"]
```

returns

> {"longitude", "latitude", "time", "time_weights", "date", "aet"}

Importing all datasets works except:

`Import["data.nc", {"Datasets", "aet"}]` with the error "Cannot import data as NetCDF format."

"aet" is the most relevant variables that changes in space ("longitude", "latitude") and in time ("time")

Thank you for your help.
tanjona

N.B. I tried to open the "data.nc" in a different software and it extracts "aet".

Comment: Is there any way to share the file, or is it too large to post somewhere (like dropbox)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the file too large to share.

Comment: If your file is compliant with netCDF-4, then HDF5 Importer may help. What happens when you try `Import["data.nc", {"HDF5", "Data", "aet"}]`?

Comment: Using your suggestion, I get "Import::fmterr: Cannot import data as HDF5 format."  Would it possible that the file is too large >1 GB to be imported? I doubt! The other rationale would be that there is something strange/mathematica incompatible with the data.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using? If the file is just over 1 GB then size shouldn't be a problem. Are you sure there is no way you can share this file with us (dropbox, google drive, anything)?

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I need to double check with the data contributors first if I can share file...let you know asap.

Comment: I am using Mathematica 11.2. Apparently, the problem is with the file. After we recreated the file in Python, Mathematica is now able to  import the newly exported data. It is a temporary solution but it works!